# wxpython, hidding and showing an object with its defined flags

Tags: python, wxpython

If I add an item to a sizer, with a few flags; it works great. But if I hide it and then show it back again, it shows up but without using the flags!!! Why? How can I fix it?

ex:

```
sizer.Add(self.listb, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)  # -> works great
.
.
self.listb.Hide()  
self.listb.Show()  # --> brings back the item without the flag
.
.
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the controls Show/Hide functions, try using the BoxSizer's Show/Hide functions.

```
.
.
sizer.Add(self.listb, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)  # -> works great
sizer.Show(self.listb, False)
sizer.Show(self.listb, True)
.
.
```

You could also try adding **sizer.Layout()** to the end if it still does not solve your problem and refresh the dimensions.

(If using self.listb as the first arg fails, try passing the index number of your item within the BoxSizer, can't quite remember which one is correct ;)